# Warning: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper

Tags: python, pip

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail
>   in a future version of pip. Please see
>   https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the
>   underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m
>   pip' instead of running pip directly.

When I directly type `pip list` to the terminal, I get the above warning. What does it mean exactly?

Should I always use it as `python3 -m pip list`? If I use it in that way, same output (list of packages) comes up without any warning.

p.s. : I am on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: Can you use `python3 -m pip list` without issue?

Comment: @NaruS yes, when used in that way, the warning disappears.

Comment: In this case, I personally recommend attempting a reinstall of pip as this issue is rather hard to fix otherwise (Tends to be a person to person fix from what ive read)

If you don';t want to do this you will have to use `python3 -m pip [package (in your case list)]` sadly this does stop you from being more verbose when it comes to invoking pip

Comment: You can use this procedure to revert back to older pip version https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599#issuecomment-414157896

Comment: this actually solved the problem, but I will wait for other possible answers. Thanks!

Comment: @NaruS i was revisiting this question and figured that it should be `python -m pip [**install** package (in your case list)]` in your comment, if I am not wrong. If you think I am right, don't delete your comment and let mine stay here, notify me otherwise, please.

Comment: This fixed it for me and explained it:  https://www.discoverbits.in/1971/warning-being-invoked-script-wrapper-this-will-future-version

Answer (score 44):

I faced the same issue but on Windows. Reinstalling `pip` worked for me. You can force a reinstall of `pip` with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

For Python3 Versions:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

Comment: I guess it is about using pip 9 instead of pip 20, which at least was the way I solved it

Answer (score 13):

I also faced the same problem when I switched to **zsh** shell from bash.

*The solution was simple but I didn't notice it at first.*

After I installed pip, I saw this warning

> pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper

First I tried this solution

> python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip

But then I ran into this issue:

[image: Screenshot from 2020-10-07 13-42-32]

Then I searched how to add `PYTHONPATH`. I opened my `.zshrc` and say these lines were commented

> `# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.`

I uncommented the line that followed, and my misery vanished.

[image: Screenshot from 2020-10-07 13-38-17]

Now when I ran,

> python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip

Then the warnings of `not in path` disappeared in thin air, leaving me with a clean output.

[image: Screenshot from 2020-10-07 13-55-34]

I hope this would help anybody who ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

After the PIP upgrade, because the boot file (/usr/bin/pip) has not been changed, the old boot file is still used,

Old PIP startup file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# GENERATED BY DEBIAN
import sys

# Run the main entry point, similarly to how setuptools does it, but because
# we didn't install the actual entry point from setup.py, don't use the
# pkg_resources API.
from pip import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

New PIP startup file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

The solution is as follows:

vi open /usr/bin/pip to add new code to save,

After this operation, there is no need to add "python -m" to run pip, and there will be no warning

Comment: sounds like a really bad idea. To muck around this deep, this freely without understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem after I **updated pip to 20.1.x version through Pycharm**. I've found one way to ensure that you can use `pip install xxx` in emergency case:

1. Open the folder containing pip (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib` in my win10 laptop)
2. You may find two folders separately belongs to the old version pip and newly installed pip (e.g. `./pip19_xxx` for your old one and `./pip` for the newly installed one
3. Delete the folder of the new version pip (e.g. `./pip`)
4. (IF NECESSARY) Change environment PATH in windows10
5. Test `pip install xxx` or `python -m pip install xxx` in `cmd`, it should work by now

Answer (score 2):

***Let me preface this by saying I am still very green with python and linux in general so I may be off base with my guidance here but I digress...***

You might want check the location of the `pip` module you are invoking when you use the `pip`command.  for me, I found out that when I would update and modify the `pip` command, it would update the `pip` file on my `~/.local/bin` directory but when I would run it, it would default to the `pip` command located in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

run the command

```
    pip install --upgrade pip
```

for me this command returned:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
>   Requirement already up-to-date: pip in **./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (20.1.1)**

Note the file location and version (in bold).

check your path variables and the default pip that executes default by running the these 2 commands respectively

```
    echo $PATH
```

and

```
    which pip
```

god willing, they'll be congruent otherwise you'll have to either alter your the path variable directories making sure that the directory for your desired pip module is first or you'll have to delete the pip file from the director that you dont want use (i.e. the directory that came up when you ran ***which pip*** if that is not the same as the directory listed when you ***updated pip***)

For me, removing the pip files in the `usr/local/bin` worked like a charm.  Also check that the pip files that you want to use are referencing the correct version of python at the top of their scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.cli.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

The other file originally referenced usr/bin/python (Python 2.7) instead of usr/bin/python3 (python 3.6.9) as I wanted initially.

Like I said before, I am just getting started with linux and python so take this with a grain of salt. Nevertheless, I no longer get this pip warning after taking these steps.  Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Removing pip files referring python 2.x fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by upgrading `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: He is on ubuntu, so pip will be probably provided by ubuntu as package. Therefore he should use apt to upgrade the pip package.

Comment: I don't think so, because my pip was already up to date, it was 20.xx and the problem got solved only when I uninstall pip and download pip 9.xx

Comment: It is advised to manage a pip installation via the package manager that installed it (see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599): 
"Only ever use your system package manager to upgrade the system pip. The system installed pip is owned by the distribution, and if you don't use distribution-supplied tools to manage it, you will hit problems."

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
 python -m pip install [module_name]
```

This will resolve warning issue

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
python3 -m pip install <package name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by executing the following  commands.

1. python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reninstall pip
2. Add python to the path in ~/.bash_profile.
   like PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by doing the following

1.Check that you are not having two versions of python.If you are having then uninstall one.

If the problem does not resolve after doing these then uninstall all the python installed in your pc and then again install it.

Comment: This is more kind of comment, not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6 after I ran `pip3 install --upgrade pip`. (The original pip version installed by `apt install python3-pip` was 9.0, but I wanted pip >= 10.0 so I could use `pip list -v`.)

**Step 1: Check the `pip` paths**

I found that there were several pips installed in various locations on my machine, and it was causing problems. Use these commands to see which pips are being executed.

```sh
pip --version
pip3 --version
type -a pip pip3 # show all the locations for pip and pip3
```

**Step 2: Fix the `pip` paths**

This step will be highly individual. You have to figure out for yourself which one to keep and which ones to remove. Here are some example commands that may be helpful:

```sh
# remove ~/.local/bin/pip
cd ~/.local/bin
mv pip pip.bak
hash -r # important, reset bash command cache!

# remove the old pip 9.0
sudo apt purge python3-pip
```

**Step 3: Upgrade `pip`**

Run the commands from Step 1 again to verify everything looks good. Then upgrade pip:

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade pip

# if you get permission denied above, the install for --user
pip3 install --user --upgrade pip

# validate everything looks right
pip --version
pip3 --version
type -a pip pip3 # show all the locations for pip and pip3
```

Comment: after removing the old pip , you'll need to reinstall it again before upgrading it: sudo apt install --upgrade python3-pip -y