# virtualenv doesn't work correctly on windows

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I am trying to use venv for my project and it doesn't work correctly.
So first of all I am activating my venv and than use command "pip freeze" to check if there are no modules installed from my computer. And there is an output^

```
user@DESKTOP-JMJSO6O C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\Scripts                                          
$ activate                                                                                        

(app) user@DESKTOP-JMJSO6O C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\Scripts                                    
$ pip freeze                                                                                      
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.     
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.        
accessify==0.3.1                                                                                  
appdirs==1.4.3                                                                                    
attrs==19.3.0                                                                                     
backcall==0.1.0                                                                                   
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2                                                                             
bleach==3.1.0                                                                                     
bs4==0.0.1    
...
```

And that is incorrect because I have no modules installed in this venv. What could be the problem?

UPD:
Trying pip --version with venv:

```
(app) user@DESKTOP-JMJSO6O C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\Scripts $ pip --version
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future 
version of pip. Please see github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the 
underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead 
of running pip directly. pip 20.0.2 from 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

Also I have founded another problem. For example, I have two python files in one directory:

```
- app/
    - main.py
    - conf.py
```

And when I am trying to import `conf` as module in `main.py`, I got the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conf'`
Maybe the problem is with Windows? Becuase on the laptop with Windows I don't have any problems like that.

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip freeze` ?

Comment: @Dionys the same output

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this problem is caused by two versions of `pip`, or a fail update attempt.
I suggest that you try following these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60574559/6136361).

Alternatively try running `where pip` and `pip --version` inside and out side the virtual-env and look for differences.

I hope you'll figure this out, the github thread suggests the problem still doesn't have an obvious solution.

Comment: It launches from the incorrect directory:
(app) user@DESKTOP-JMJSO6O C:\Users\user\Desktop\app\Scripts
$ pip --version
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

Comment: It's hard to read it like that, can you edit that into your question as a code block, and also add the output for the same command outside venv. it might also be useful if you could specify the correct directory from which it should run.