# Pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently on macOS Big Sur and recently updated pip from 19.2.3 to 20.3.3 but now there's the old wrapper script error.
I searched online for solutions and tried all of them but nothing worked.

So currently I have python 3.8.2 (I uninstalled my python 3.7.4)

and I added the python 3.8 to `$PATH` and now

`echo $PATH` displays `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin`

but that does not help with anything

I also tried reinstalling but it didn't work either

Are there any other solutions I could try?
Is the problem because of pathing?

If this still persists, will it cause any error in the future (what kind of errors will it cause to my Mac/applications?)

> Warning message:  WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script
> wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip. Please see
> https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the
> underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m
> pip' instead of running pip directly. pip 20.3.3 from
> /Users/syanreah/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip
> (python 3.8)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a path issue. Run `type -a pip pip3` to find all of the pip locations. Then run each one to see if any of them do not give the "old script wrapper" warning. Example:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/pip --version
```

If you "bad" ones, rename them to `pip.bak`, so that the "good" one will be first in the path.

For more details, see [Warning: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029215/warning-pip-is-being-invoked-by-an-old-script-wrapper/69035028#69035028)